# jQuery Validate plugin ignoreTitle on single field?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I know you can ignore the title attributes as error messages for a form with the following code:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
  ignoreTitle:true
});
```

However, i'd like to know if this can be done for a single field. The reason I'm asking is because I'd like to have one of my fields return a message containing HTML and not just a string message.

Is there any way to conditionally put HTML within `title` attributes?

Comment: What's the purpose of this?  Is it just so your page passes the W3C HTML Validator?  Can you show more code and a jsFiddle demo so future readers can benefit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Quote:  Is there any way to conditionally put HTML within title
>   attributes?

No, there is not.   But you can designate custom messages within the `messages` option for that one field instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').validate({
        //  your other rules and/or options
        messages: {
            myfieldname: {
                myrule: "this is my <b>custom</b> message"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

(Yes, it looks like HTML is allowed)

**Working Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/4KGjD/

[See documentation.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options)

> **messages**, *Options,   Default: the default message for the method used*
>
> Key/value pairs defining custom messages. Key is the name of an
>   element, value the message to display for that element. Instead of a
>   plain message another map with specific messages for each rule can be
>   used. Overrides the title attribute of an element or the default
>   message for the method (in that order). Each message can be a String
>   or a Callback. The callback is called in the scope of the validator
>   and with the rule's parameters as the first and the element as the
>   second arugment, it must return a String to display as the message.

Answer (score 0):

I realized it might be simpler **in my case** just to remove the `title` attribute before validation and add it back if there is an error.

So here's the general idea of the Javascript I went with:

```
//BEFORE validation, remove title attribute:
var password=$('#myForm).find('input[type=password]');
var title=password.attr('title');
password.removeAttr('title');

//If there is an error, add back the title attribute 
password.attr('title', title);
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<input id="password" title='Password must be at least 8 characters, 1 number, 1 upper and 1 lower case letters'  placeholder='At least 8 chars, 1 num, 1 upper'
name="password" type="password" />
<div class='error'>
<ul id='passwordError' style='display:none'>
    <li>Password must be at least:</li>
    <li> 8 characters </li>
    <li> 1 upper, 1 lower case letter</li>
    <li> 1 number</li>  
</ul>               
</div>
```

Comment: Simpler than what? That seems really verbose for what you're trying to achieve.  What's wrong with my answer?  And why do this in the first place if you're going to manipulate the DOM into what it could have been all along?  In other words, it really makes no difference to write the HTML yourself or write the HTML with JavaScript... in both cases, you still have a `title` `attribute` that contains HTML entities.

Comment: Hi @Sparky, I simplified my example for the point of discussion. In reality, all of the forms on my site are part of a larger, though unified codebase where the `validate()` is wrapped in `ajaxSubmit()`, etc. I just found it too difficult to figure out how to add custom messages in the manner you suggest and not break everything. It was just easier for me to manipulate my form submission workflow how I suggest. The bottom line is your way works great and is the better general solution. I was only describing a hack that I got to work quickly without having to blow up my existing code.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  I think if your `.validate()` wasn't "wrapped" within anything, you might have an easier time manipulating it.  In other words, `.validate()` should only be called _once_ upon DOM ready to initialize the plugin with your options/rules, etc.  Then there are other built-in methods you can use to make dynamic changes, test validity, submit with ajax, or hook into other events.  Food for thought for your future endeavors.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The fact that `.validate()` should only be called *once* was something I didn't actually realize though the fact that I couldn't get it to work if wrapped by `ajaxSubmit()` explains why. So my actual code makes use of `$(form).validate().form()` and **not** `$('#myForm').validate()`. Sorry for creating the confusion, I should have probably just said that in my question. Thanks again for your help. I'll accept your answer to encourage best practices and others can read my answer just as an aside.

Comment: No worries.  It seems to be a common mistake.  Probably a third of the SO question about this plugin have it wrapped inside of a `click` handler.  Again, the plugin would not even be initialized until after the first click... you get the idea.  Anytime after `.validate()`, try `$('#myform').valid();` to simply do an instant validity check; it also returns a `true/false` boolean.

Comment: Yep, I had had it wrapped in `click` too, drove me crazy for a few days! I really love the jQuery Validate plugin, very impressive piece of work and my whole site is full of it, but the documentation is not the best.

Comment: Yeah, `.valid()` is the best way to trigger full form validation when you can't get a submit event.